# Awesome menu in a table cell detect click

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi im coding an awesome menu button on each cell, the problem is that I need to know which Awesome Menu view I´m clicking

This is my function to add the Awesome Menu view to each cell

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ActivasTableViewCell";

    ActivasTableViewCell *cell = (ActivasTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivasTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    UIImage *storyMenuItemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem.png"];
    UIImage *storyMenuItemImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem-highlighted.png"];

    UIImage *starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-star.png"];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem1 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem2 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];

    NSArray *menus = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2,nil];

    AwesomeMenuItem *startItem = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-addbutton.png"]
                                                       highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-addbutton-highlighted.png"]
                                                           ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-plus.png"]
                                                highlightedContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-plus-highlighted.png"]];

    AwesomeMenu *menu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds startItem:startItem optionMenus:menus];
    menu.delegate = self;

    menu.menuWholeAngle = M_PI_2*3;
    menu.farRadius = 50.0f;
    menu.endRadius = 50.0f;
    menu.nearRadius = 30.0f;
    menu.animationDuration = 0.3f;

    menu.startPoint = CGPointMake(290.0,166.0);

    [cell addSubview:menu];

    return cell;
}
```

This are my functions for detecting a click on the view

```
- (void)awesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    NSLog(@"Select the index : %d",idx);
}
- (void)awesomeMenuDidFinishAnimationClose:(AwesomeMenu *)menu {
    NSLog(@"Menu was closed!");
}
- (void)awesomeMenuDidFinishAnimationOpen:(AwesomeMenu *)menu {
    NSLog(@"Menu is open!");
}
```

Comment: set AwesomeMenu tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath method using indexPath.row and access via that tag value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could take.

1. If you only have one section in your table, you could assign the `tag` property of each `AwesomeMenu` object to the value of whatever `indexPath.row` is in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. You could add a property to `AwesomeMenu` for the purpose of identifying the row or indexPath it is located at:

   ```
   @interface AwesomeMenu : NSObject
   ...
   @property (nonatomic) int rowIndex;                      //  If you only need the row index
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;    //  If you need row and section
   ...
   @end
   ```
3. Or, you could get the cell for the `AwesomeMenu` and then get its `indexPath` from the table:

   ```
   - (void)awesomeMenuDidFinishAnimationClose:(AwesomeMenu *)menu {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self getTableViewCellForView: menu];
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myMenuTable indexPathForCell: cell];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *) getTableViewCellForView: (UIView *) view {
       UIView *parentView = view;
       while (parentView) {
           if ([parentView isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
               return (UITableViewCell *) parentView;
           }
           parentView = parentView.superview;
       }
       return nil;
   }
   ```